# Screen turns black after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

I have upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04 on my Sony Vaio VPCW11S1E with no apparent problem. However, when I boot, after about 25 seconds the screen turns completely black and I get no response to mouse or screen. After another 45 seconds the computer switches into a powersafe mode. Then, I can press the space bar and the computer resumes and the screen comes back on. This repeats and it takes me 3-4 such cycles to see my desktop. Everything looks OK there (at least for the short period I see it).

I tried a text console via Ctrl-Alt-F1, but get the same behavior. When I get to the grub selection, I can stay there and move the cursor around without the screen switching off. So the problem seems to be in Ubuntu and not in the hardware.

I don't really know what to do or try. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you find a solution and if yes, can you share it please ?
However, if I start my ubuntu in upstart mode, it's ok, no issue. thanks

Comment: i'm having similar problem but when `Lock` (automatic lock after screen turns off) is `On` this doesn't seem to happen.